# Convert Java program to Shell script

Tags: java, shell, maven

If I setup a maven project and write a Java program with main method, I want to convert this program to an equivalent shell script. In other words, the shell script should accept the arguments and should behave in the same way that the java program would behave when main method is called with arguments. How do I achieve this?

Comment: By reimplementing all of the Java program logic in shell script.

Comment: I am not very good at shell programming. If there is a way to convert java program to shell, that would be better

Comment: There is no such "convert java to shell" program. Why can't you call the existing Java program from your shell?

Comment: That's what I will have to do if we can't convert java to shell. I thought if there is a plugin that does this, I might use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shell script's **variable arguments** to achieve this. First you can write your logic in **Java** and then pass all the arguments from shell script to it.

```
#! /bin/bash
java <class_name> $@
```

**$@** will pass all the arguments to the Java program.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Print_Series3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n,i,pr=0;
   System.out.printf("Enter the range of number(Limit):");
    n=sc.nextInt();
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            pr=(int) (2*Math.pow(i,2)+1);
            System.out.print(pr+" ");
        }
        else
        {
            pr=(int) (2*Math.pow(i,2)-1);
            System.out.printf(pr+" ");
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).